# Confusion with Angular 2 directory structure when almost all components are shared

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, directory-structure, angular2-routing

I started developing a new Angular 2 application and I am trying to follow the official Angular 2 style guide. Most part of my application is composed by a series of modules (about ~10 of them) that know nothing about each other. As a result I can use lazy loading and access these modules though the Angular 2 router.

```
|- app
|   |- +module1
|   |   |- module1-list
|   |   |   |- module1-list.component.html
|   |   |   |- module1-list.component.ts
|   |   |- module1-view
|   |   |   |- module1-view.component.html
|   |   |   |- module1-view.component.ts
|   |   |- shared
|   |   |   |- module1.model.ts
|   |   |   |- module1.service.ts
|   |   |- module1-container.component.html
|   |   |- module1-container.component.ts
|   |- +module2
|   |   |- <same structure with module1>
```

In the above diagram, the `moduleX-container.component` component is the page the router points to. All the other components of `moduleX` are attached to it.

However, there is some application modules, `foo` and `bar`, that need to use components from all other modules. According to the official Angular 2 style guide, shared components have to be placed under the `shared` folder. As a result my directory structure becomes like this:

```
|- app
|   |- +foo (this makes use of all the components under /app/shared/)
|   |   |- foo-container.component.html
|   |   |- foo-container.component.ts
|   |- +bar (this makes use of all the components under /app/shared/)
|   |   |- bar-container.component.html
|   |   |- bar-container.component.ts
|   |- +module1
|   |   |- module1-container.component.html
|   |   |- module1-container.component.ts
|   |- +module2
|   |   |- module2-container.component.html
|   |   |- module2-container.component.ts
|   |- shared
|   |   |- module1
|   |   |   |- module1-list
|   |   |   |   |- module1-list.component.html
|   |   |   |   |- module1-list.component.ts
|   |   |   |- module1-view
|   |   |   |   |- module1-view.component.html
|   |   |   |   |- module1-view.component.ts
|   |   |   |- shared
|   |   |   |   |- module1.model.ts
|   |   |   |   |- module1.service.ts
|   |   |- module2
|   |   |   |- <same structure with module1>
```

As you can see, now almost all my code is placed under the `shared` folder. As a result the lazy loaded components (the ones starting with `+`) in the app folder would just hold the wireframe for pages accessing shared components. Is that a good structure? It looks like it is compatible with the official Angular 2 style guide, but at the same time is feels kinda strange to have the 95% of my code under the `shared` folder.

EDIT 1:

Also, I would like `module1-view.component` and `module1-list.component` to be loaded by (or nested under) lazy and non-lazy loaded components. As a result, in my first directory structure approach, having `module1-view.component` and `module1-list.component` under a lazy-loaded parent component (`+module1`) seems wrong.

What do you think? Is it indeed compatible or I am misreading something in the style guide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are misreading the style guide. Under shared components and directives should really be placed only components and directives that are nested in more than one parent components. I.e. if you have header component for the grid component and also for the product list component, you should put the header component in shared folder. Or some similar component which is nested in more than one other component and is not stand-alone component, or to say "feature component". Another example is services which you can share with different components.
In the end, it is not of a such importance, because only purpose of the structure is to find and locate components quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply my friend! I see your point, but I am still a little bit confused.  After some edits on my initial question: `module1-list.component` and `module1-view.component` are both nested/used under/in `foo-container.component` and `bar-container.component` components. Also, `module1-container.component` is a lazy loaded component (thus the `+` in the folder name) because it is loaded using the router. However, the `module1-list.component` should be able to load from both lazy and non-lazy loaded components; As a result it kinda feels wrong to be under a lazy-loaded folder.